# marker not visible on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing a tracking application which tracks the path taken by user and plots a polyline on that
I am trying to add marker at certain position while tracking but the marker is not showing on the map
I have added the marker in onMapReady method but still it is not visible on the map

My source code

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
private var lastKnownLocation: Location? = null
private var locationPermissionGranted: Boolean = false
private lateinit var placesClient: PlacesClient
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 121
private val REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION: Int = 0
val polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
private val mapsActivityViewModel: MapsActivityViewModel by viewModels {
    MapsActivityViewModelFactory(getTrackingRepository())
}
private fun getTrackingApplicationInstance() = application as TrackingApplication
private fun getTrackingRepository() = getTrackingApplicationInstance().trackingRepository

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    Places.initialize(applicationContext, getString(R.string.maps_api_key))
    placesClient = Places.createClient(this)

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    val isActivityRecognitionPermissionFree = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q
    val isActivityRecognitionPermissionGranted = EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
    )

    mapsActivityViewModel.lastTrackingEntity.observe(this) { lastTrackingEntity ->
        lastTrackingEntity ?: return@observe
        addLocationToRoute(lastTrackingEntity)
    }


    if (isActivityRecognitionPermissionFree || isActivityRecognitionPermissionGranted) {
       
        setupLocationChangeListener()
    } else {
      
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            host = this,
            rationale = "For showing your step counts and calculate the average pace.",
            requestCode = REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
            perms = *arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
        )
    }

}

private fun addLocationToRoute(lastTrackingEntity: TrackingEntity) {
    mMap.clear()
    val newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng()
    polylineOptions.points.add(newLatLng)
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions)

}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    getLocationPermission()
    updateLocationUI()
    getDeviceLocation()

    mMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(16.667421, 74.819688))
            .title("Marker in Sydney")
            .icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)
            )
    )

}

val locationcallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

        locationResult.locations.forEach {
            val trackingEntity =
                TrackingEntity(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis, it.latitude, it.longitude)
            mapsActivityViewModel.insert(trackingEntity)
        }

    }
}

private fun setupLocationChangeListener() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        val locationRequest = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority =
            com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000 // 5000ms (5s)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            return
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationcallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    } else {

        getLocationPermission()
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun updateLocationUI() {
    try {
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        } else {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false
            mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
            lastKnownLocation = null
            getLocationPermission()
        }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun getDeviceLocation() {

    try {
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                    lastKnownLocation = task.result
                    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        mMap.moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                LatLng(
                                    lastKnownLocation!!.latitude,
                                    lastKnownLocation!!.longitude
                                ), 18.0F
                            )
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
                    mMap.moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newLatLngZoom(sydney, 18.0F)
                    )
                    mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
    }
}

private fun getLocationPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        locationPermissionGranted = true
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    locationPermissionGranted = false
    when (requestCode) {
        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                locationPermissionGranted = true
            }
        }
    }
    updateLocationUI()
}
```

}